# Updating pango broke gtkmm (Arch)

Tags: c++, linux, cairo, gtkmm, pango

I just updated the `pango` package (running Arch Linux), and now I can't link any of my gtkmm code. Here's the error:

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.1/../../../../lib/libpangocairo-1.0.so: undefined reference to``g_type_class_adjust_private_offset'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

What could the issue be? I'm rather new to gtkmm, and I had just sorted out most of the initial problems - this threw me off a bit. Haven't been able to find a solution online, either.

I'm not using a makefile, I'm just running the standard `` g++`pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-3.0`file.cc ``.

I'd appreciate any help.

I should also mention that I updated the `cairo` package, too, to see if it'd fix anything. No luck.

Comment: I believe, this question would be more appropriate to http://superuser.com/ , another StackExchange site.